# Using sequential approach to prove $\sin(\pi x)$ is only continuous when $x$ is an integer

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, continuity

Let
$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
\sin(\pi x) & \text{if $x$ is rational, and} \\
0 & \text{if $x$ is irrational.}
\end{cases}$$
Prove, by the sequential approach, that the function $f$ is only continuous at $x$ when $x$ is integer.

I would like to ask how do we do this using the sequential approach? I am stuck at how to define the sequence of $x$ in the above question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Let's generalize a bit!** Suppose that $f_1,f_2$ are continuous maps and

$$f(x)=\begin{cases} f_1(x) & x\in \mathbb{Q} \\
f_2(x) & x \notin \mathbb{Q}\end{cases}$$

Let's prove that $f$ is continuous at $x_0$ if $f_1(x_0) = f_2(x_0)$ and not continuous otherwise.

*Suppose that $f_1(x_0) = f_2 (x_0)$*

Take $\epsilon >0$. By definition it exists $\delta_1$ such that for $\vert x- x_0 \vert < \delta_1$ you have $\vert f_1(x) - f_1(x_0) \vert < \epsilon$. It exists also $\delta_2$ with similar inequalities for $f_2$. Now take $\delta = \min\{\delta_1, \delta_1\}$. For $\vert x - x_0 \vert < \delta$, you have $\vert f(x) - f(x_0) \vert < \delta$ proving continuity at $x_0$.

*Now suppose that $f_1(x_0) \neq f_2 (x_0)$*

Suppose that $x_0 \in \mathbb Q$. The sequence $y_n= x_0+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{n}$ is a sequence of irrationals converging to $x_0$. Therefore:

$$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} f(y_n) = f_2(x_0) \neq f_1(x_0) = f(x_0)$$
proving that $f$ is not continuous at $x_0$.

And if $x_0 \notin \mathbb Q$, get a similar conclusion considering the sequence of rationals $z_n=x_0+1/n$.

**You can apply this result to $f_1(x) = \sin \left(\pi x \right)$ and $f_2(x) = 0$.**

Comment: May I know why we take the min of d1 and d2 instead of the maximum of d1 and d2? Thank you.

Comment: $u < \min(\delta_1, \delta_2)$ ensures that $u < \delta_1$ and  $u < \delta_2$. That's not the case with the max as you can have $\delta_1 < u < \delta_2$.

Answer (score 1):

The other answer is great, but it is sometimes helpful to see a concrete example.  As such, I will directly answer the question asked here, rather than prove a more general result.  (The general result is great—I am attempting to add to the existing answer, and am in no way suggesting that it is insufficient).

I will assume that it is already known that $\sin$ is a continuous function.

#### The function is not continuous at $x \not\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Let $x$ be a real number which is not an integer.  It is sufficient to show that there exist two sequences $a_n, b_n \to x$ such that
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} f(a_n) \ne \lim_{n\to\infty} f(b_n). $$

1. Choose a sequence $a_n \to x$ where each $a_n$ is irrational.  If this needs to be more concrete, choose $a_n \in (x, x+\frac{1}{n})$—the irrationals are dense in the reals, so such a choice always exists.  Note that $f(a_n) = 0$ for all $n$, and so $\lim_{n\to\infty} f(a_n) = 0$.
2. Choose a sequence $b_n \to x$ where each $b_n$ is rational.  Again, if this needs to be more concrete, choose $b_n \in (x,x+\frac{1}{n})$.  Then $f(b_n) = \sin(b_n \pi)$ for all $n$.  Using the continuity of $\sin$, it then follows that $\lim_{n\to\infty} f(b_n) = \lim_{n\to\infty} \sin(b_n \pi) = \sin(\pi x)$.

Thus $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ are sequences with the desired properties.

#### The function is continuous at $x \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Fix some $x \in \mathbb{Z}$ and choose a sequence $c_n \to x$.  Fix $\varepsilon > 0$.  Observe that $\sin(\pi x) = 0$, hence it is reasonable to expect that $\lim_{n\to x} f(c_n) = 0$.  As $\sin$ is continuous, there exists some $N$ so large that $n > N$ implies that $|\sin(\pi c_n) - 0| < \varepsilon$.  Hence for any $n > N$, it follows that
$$
|f(c_n) - 0|
= |f(c_n)|
\overset{*}{\le} \max\{ 0, |\sin(\pi c_n)|\}
< \varepsilon, $$
which completes the proof.

[*] Note that the first inequality follows from the fact that either $c_n$ is rational, and $f(c_n) = \sin(\pi c_n)$; or $c_n$ is irrational, and $f(c_n) = 0$.  In either case, $f(c_n) \le \max\{0,\sin(\pi c_n)\}$.